# Improve random sample function

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, random, artificial-intelligence

I have the following function to generate a random sample from an original data set:

```
def randomSampling(originalData):
    a = np.random.random_integers(0, 500, size=originalData.shape)

    #Number of elements in the result. We split in a half because we want a 50% sample
    N=round(parkinsonData.shape[0]/2)

    result = np.zeros(originalData.shape)
    ia = np.arange(result.size)

    #cast to float the sum of the flat a array
    tw = float(np.sum(a.ravel()))

    result.ravel()[np.random.choice(ia, p=a.ravel()/tw,size=N, replace=False)]=1
    return result
```

My purpose is to achieve a subset of original data that has 50% of the size of the original set. This way I can execute this function two times, one to achieve training subset and another to test subset.

My problem is that in the original data I have a field called `status` that have values `0` or `1`. And I want to keep the proportionality between both set of classes in the subsets of training and test.

How can I do this with python? Also I am not sure that the function is achieving to create the samples with the half of the registers of the original set. Theoretically, this should ensure that the size is 50%: `N=round(parkinsonData.shape[0]/2)`

Comment: Is the order of samples important? If not, just split by status first, then take 50% from both and combine?

Comment: @tobias_k Yes it is important, but I can take your approach and then shuffle all, right?